# How to enable a parameter when a choice is choose in Jenkins Build with parameters option

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline with parameters where I want to enable certain parameter only when the option is chose from the previous parameter.

Say for ex: In the choice parameter, I have a choice called "India" when I choose, I want a text box to be displayed with the Label Value called "Enter your State". I tried with Active Choice Reactive Parameter and Extended Choice parameter.

Could someone help me with the solution/code for the above mentioned situation.

Comment: From you description it seems like "Extended Choice parameter" should do what you want. Can you please describe how that plugin does not satisfy your need?

Comment: Seems already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902786/how-to-enable-disable-a-textbox-in-groovy-script