# how to enable/disable a textbox in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have couple of parameters in my Jenkins pipeline. Where my first parameter is choice and my second parameter is Input Box contains string.

My challenge here is, when I select first value in the first parameter, 2nd parameter (input box) should be enabled if not it should not. I am currently using Extended Choice Parameter for 2nd parameter where I choose "Text Box" as parameter type. Could someone help me out how to enable and disable the parameter input on selecting values of different parameter.

Ex:
**P1 - Choice Parameter values : Enable, Disable
P2 - Extended Choice Parameter: (Text box)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P2 has to be DynamicReferenceParameter in this case, depending on P1.

```
[$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
description: '',
name: 'P2', 
omitValueField: true,
randomName: 'choice-parameter-123456', 
referencedParameters: 'P1',
script: [
    $class: 'GroovyScript', 
    fallbackScript: [
        classpath: [],
        sandbox: true,
        script: 
            'return [\'Error message\']'
    ], 
    script: [
        classpath: [], 
        sandbox: true,
        script: 
            """ 
                html=""
                if (P1.equals("firstValue")){
                    
                        html="<input name='value' value='' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
                }
                else {
                    html="Not applicable"
                }
                return html
            """
    ]
] ]
```